# Query located in cellAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I have a query located in my `cellAtIndexPath`. This query takes objects from an array at the index for the cell row, as is common. I was wondering if every time I load my `tableView` will there just be one query, or will it count as a query for every `indexPath.row`. The reason why this is important is because it could be the difference between one request and hundreds of request overtime I load the `tableView`. Is the query called for every row or just once?

Comment: I have a query located in my cellAtIndexPath? i am confused can you post some code

Comment: if you perform some network query, or time consuming computation 'in request' of UITableView, you are better to change your approach as soon, as possible. isolate your data model from your user interface and you will be fine.

Comment: You could put some logging step along with your query and you will see that it can get called extremely often (i.e. possibly multiple time for every visible cell every time the user scrolls the tableView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be called one time for each `indexPath.row` as `cellAtIndexPath` is the method called for each cell. You can try to cache it somehow to avoid loading data each time you load the table.

But the better approach would be using some framework ([Parse](https://parse.com) provides it for its database) which can help you load the data in background.

Comment: @Jojodmo please marked as answer if you find it helpful